# Spring-Kafka properties configuration for SASL fails authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, bitnami

I have a docker compose

````
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=rms_zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:9091,DOCKER_COMPOSE://:9092,MINIKUBE://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://localhost:9091,DOCKER_COMPOSE://host.docker.internal:9092
        ,MINIKUBE://host.minikube.internal:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER_COMPOSE:SASL_PLAINTEXT,
        MINIKUBE:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD=password
      - KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS=test
      - KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS=test
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
      - KAFKA_TLS_TYPE=JKS

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper```

Authentication works when I create producers and consumers within the container using a customized consumer.properties file.

```bootstrap.servers=host.docker.internal:9092
compression.type=none
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="test" password="test";
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
````

I am struggling trying to authenticate my spring kafka producer currently the setup is

`@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format(
            "%s required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";", PlainLoginModule.class.getName(), "test", "test"
    ));
        
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
}
```

}
`

and

@Service
@Log4j2
@NoArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducer
{
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

```
@PostConstruct
private void setUp()
{
    // Set the message converter to one that converts the message type to json
    kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
}

public KafkaProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

public void sendMessage(String topic, String message) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
}
```

}

I had also tried to use application.properties to set them as

`spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=host.docker.internal:9092 spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="test" password="test;`

yet still getting

(Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

Which suggests that the security is not set up or configured properly for the producer and not too sure what I am missing / if I am misunderstanding something fundamentally

Expecting kafka to try and complete SASL handshake but instead: (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)